# Crash viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear: on iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c

Since a while my app crashes in production but It has been impossible to reproduce this error in debug mode.

The error in Crashlytics is:

```
UIKit
-[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:]

SIGABRT ABORT 0x00000001825d4d74

    Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
    0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1825d4d74 __abort_with_payload + 8
    1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1825d1480 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 100
    2  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1825d141c abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 34
    3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18203fed8 _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 112
    4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18203fe30 __objc_error + 42
    5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x182052cd4 weak_entry_insert(weak_table_t*, weak_entry_t*) + 318
    6  libobjc.A.dylib                0x182058664 objc_initWeak + 324
    7  UIKit                          0x1894ce1bc -[UIViewController viewDidMoveToWindow:shouldAppearOrDisappear:] + 2068
    8  UIKit                          0x18944db5c -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1352
    9  UIKit                          0x18944d8e4 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 720
    10 UIKit                          0x189471714 -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 92
    11 UIKit                          0x18944d8e4 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 720
    12 UIKit                          0x18944d8e4 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 720
    13 UIKit                          0x189471714 -[UIScrollView _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 92
    14 UIKit                          0x18944d8e4 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 720
    15 UIKit                          0x18944d8e4 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 720
    16 UIKit                          0x18944d8e4 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 720
    17 UIKit                          0x18944d8e4 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 720
    18 UIKit                          0x18944d8e4 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 720
    19 UIKit                          0x18944d8e4 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 720
    20 UIKit                          0x18944d8e4 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 720
    21 UIKit                          0x18944d8e4 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 720
    22 UIKit                          0x18944cd90 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 156
    23 Foundation                     0x184034510 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 168
    24 UIKit                          0x18944cc04 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 820
    25 UIKit                          0x18974a078 __UIViewWasRemovedFromSuperview + 172
    26 UIKit                          0x18944bc80 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 512
    27 UIKit                          0x1897a23dc __71-[UIPresentationController _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke.629 + 1044
    28 UIKit                          0x18979c4fc -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 124
    29 UIKit                          0x18990afc8 -[_UICurrentContextPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 40
    30 UIKit                          0x1897a012c __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 188
    31 UIKit                          0x189578ad4 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 116
    32 UIKit                          0x1895788c0 -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 252
    33 UIKit                          0x1895783dc -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1240
    34 UIKit                          0x189577ef0 -[UITransitionView _transitionDidStop:finished:] + 124
    35 UIKit                          0x189489b48 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 312
    36 UIKit                          0x189489988 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 160
    37 QuartzCore                     0x186912404 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 260
    38 libdispatch.dylib              0x1824911c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    39 libdispatch.dylib              0x182495d6c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
    40 CoreFoundation                 0x1835b5f2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
    41 CoreFoundation                 0x1835b3b18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
    42 CoreFoundation                 0x1834e2048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
    43 GraphicsServices               0x184f65198 GSEventRunModal + 180
    44 UIKit                          0x1894bc628 -[UIApplication _run] + 684
    45 UIKit                          0x1894b7360 UIApplicationMain + 208
    46 <App Name>                     0x100081590 main (main.m:14)
    47 libdispatch.dylib              0x1824c45b8 (Missing)
```

Most of the logs show that the user had between 1% and 3% of RAM memory free but there are some with more than 10%.

Also my app tracks errors using Sentry but this error is not in Sentry only in Fabric.

Most of my users use iOS 10 but still there are who use iOS 9 and this crash seems that not affect these users. So it seems it is related to iOS 10.

Also I have searched here but I have not could find a solution even a clue. Someone could help me to find a clue?

**EDIT**

Regarding the comments the new code introduced that it is related with UIViewController is:

```
    - (IBAction)tapClose:(id)sender {
        [self close];
    }

    - (void)close {
        _dismissing = YES;

        CGFloat height = self.view.superview.frame.size.height;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
            [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
            _overlay.alpha = 0;
        }                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            if (finished) {
                [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                [_overlay removeFromSuperview];
                if (self.blockWhenClose) {
                    self.blockWhenClose();
                }
            }
        }];
    }

    - (void)showIn:(UIViewController *)viewcontroller {
        CGRect frame = viewcontroller.view.frame;
        CGFloat height = [self calculateHeight:frame.size.height / 2];
        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, frame.size.height, frame.size.width, height)];
        [_overlay setFrame:frame];
        _overlay.alpha = 0;
        [viewcontroller addChildViewController:self];
        [viewcontroller.view addSubview:_overlay];
        [viewcontroller.view addSubview:self.view];
        [self didMoveToParentViewController:viewcontroller];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:_duration animations:^{
            _overlay.alpha = 1;
            [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, frame.size.height - height, frame.size.width, height)];
        }];
        _show = YES;
    }
```

But I do not know where exactly the crash occurs.

Comment: `_UIViewControllerTransitionContext` implies this happens while shifting between `UIViewController`s. Are you using anything like a `Side Menu` controller or doing custom `UIViewControllerAnimation`?

Comment: The view hierarchy while transitioning looks corrupted. Can you share related code?

Comment: @KrishnaCA there are no Side Menu, and I do not introduce any UIViewControllerAnimation. There are huge changes but the only new code introduced related to UIViewController changes is that (just added in the question)

Comment: We are facing the same crash with same situation, could you find the solution?

Comment: @JordiPuigdellívol I reduce the problem although it is there. In my case is related weak references `Cannot form weak reference to instance (0x1093ae3c0) of class <class name>. It is possible that this object was over-released, or is in the process of deallocation.` because the view controller is inside a pagination view. And I could reproduce it changing between pages fast. In my case the problem occurs in the `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` when create custom view. I hope this could help you.

Comment: @AlbertoCantallops yeah I belive in my case happens in a paginated vc as well, but i can't reproduce it myself yet.. only my customers in very high intensive use :(

Answer (score 0):

For me this started with iOS 14

The problem was, I had code where the view of a controller (A) was added as a subview to another controller(B) without holding a reference to the controller(A) itself. the controller(A) was deallocated and next time the view is about to appear or disappear, it tries to notify the controller(A) which causes a crashes.

Solution:

- Manually hold a reference to the controller
- OR addChildViewController which does the above for you